# Pytest AttributeError: module 'shared' has no attribute 'config'

Tags: python

I try to mock a function but pytest is complaining about that he can't find my function and i don't really understand why.

This is my folder architecture :

```
app
  |--somefolder
      |--somecode.py
  |--shared
      |-- config.py
  |--tests
      |-- fixtures.py
```

In fixture.py i have :

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def fake_config(mocker):
    mocker.patch('shared.config.get_parameters_names', return_value=('hi', 'hello', 'world'))
```

and i have this error : `AttributeError: module 'shared' has no attribute 'config'`

In my code i can successfully import my function with this way :  `import shared.config as config` and it's working. I also have some tests in the test folder that use this import without problem, but why pytests is throwing an error ?